# Taking a file or pipe as input

Tags: python, command-line, pipe, argparse

I wish to create a python program that is used from the command line.
It has one positional argument that is a file name.
I want to also be able to pass it input from a pipe

I want to create my python program so that it behaves the same here:

`my_program.py input_data.txt`

as it does here

`cat input_data.txt | my_program.py`

I have built programs that do one or the other, but I'm not sure how to conveniently handle both.
I usually use argparse to do this stuff so I was hoping there is an argparse based solution but if not that's fine.

Comment: Your program is supposed to read the contents of the csv file correct?

Comment: Seriously, don't bother.  It's extra work that you do not need to do.  Instead of `my_program.py input_data.txt`, you let the shell do the work and write `my_program.py < input_data.txt`. It's a better mind set anyway.

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't do this.  Get in the habit of redirecting input, and life becomes much better.  If you do want to do this, just add a few lines at the start:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    in_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
else:
    in_file = sys.stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `my_program.py` read the name of the file in the argument.

If there is an argument, it will do the standard csv reader. But if it is piped a program, it will read the standard input from the pipe.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import csv

arg = sys.argv[1] #this saves the filename to arg from the command line

if len(sys.argv) > 1: #if given an argument, run this
    with open(arg, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)

else: #if not given an argument, run this
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stdout.write(line)

        with open(line, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                print(row)
```

You can edit the contents of the csv reader below depending on what your file looks like.